# Links aren't linking

Tags: hyperlink

When I click on my links, they do not go anywhere; I clicked on "about Us" , nothing. I looked at Lucas Green's answer to anc1revv, but I'm still drawing a blank. I appreciate any ideas. Also the links do not turn yellow when I hover. I know it's something minor.
Sorry, I meant turn orange when I hover.
Thank you

```
<body>

<div id="container">
        <div id="header">
           <img class="logo" src="images/green-light.jpg" alt="Green Light Data Technologies" />
           <img class="header-star-left" src="images/arrow2.jpg" alt="All Systems Go" />
           <img class="header-star-rt" src="images/arrow2.jpg" alt="All Systems Go" />
           <h1>Green Light Data Technologies</h1>
           <h2>Keeping All Systems GO!</h2>
        </div><!--/#header-->

        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html" target="_blank">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutus.html" target="_blank">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!--/#nav-->

        <div id="content-home">
            <h1>Welcome to Green Light Data Technologies!</h1>
            <p>Thank you for visiting our site. Here you will find the latest cabling products, accessories and expert advise on their use. Our employees are well trained, product knowledgeable and are pleased to assist you.
            Our website is designed to be easy to navigate and easy to learn more about Green Light product lines that may be of interest to you.
            We are committed to supplying excellent electronic components that will meet your needs and to the development of unique future electronic components that will open new vistas in electronics. We actively pursue the improvement of existing products, the strengthening of newly developed products.</p>
        </div><!--/#content-->

</div><!--/#container-->

</body>
</html>

/* MAIN NAVIGATION
----------------------------------- */
#nav { 
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
    height: 53px;
    padding: 0; 
    margin: 0;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 205px;
    margin-left: 1em;
}

#nav ul li {
    float: left;    
    line-height: 53px; 
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 50px 0 0;
}

#nav ul li a {
        font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        font-weight: bold;
        /*color: #fff;*/
        color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
    position: relative;
        bottom: -5px;
    background-color: orange;
    border-bottom: 2px dotted #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its probably your browser's popup blocker preventing the `_blank` link opening a new popup. look at the top (for firefox and chrome) or bottom (for IE) for notifications to allow popup.
orange hover links are working as expected.
check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6yY9u/) I added this:

```
body {
    background-color: #999999;
}
```

so your menu is visible.

Comment: Thank you Volkan. I will make modifications with your tips and let you know.

Comment: Thanks again. I removed the _blank, same problem. I turned off the popup blocker, no luck. I'll keep it at it. BTW, I'm, using Safari 6.1 on Mtn. Lion. This also happens on Firefox.